# MySQL редактирование базы на python

Tags: python, mysql, linux, ubuntu, vds

Имею библиотеку mysql.connector на python. Имею VDS и MySQL базу данных на нём, настроил подключение извне и всё. Программирую систему авторизации (регистрация вносит аккаунты в базу данных). Не нашел нормального ответа на вопрос: у меня есть база данных accs таблица accounts, с 2 строками: login, password. Программа считывает введённые данные в переменные . Как их вписать в эти строки? И какой лучше шифровщик посоветуете?

Answer (score 1):

Мне нравится библиотека cryptography и его модуль Fernet. Также можно покопать в сторону Python hashlib.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

cipher_key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher = Fernet(cipher_key)
text = b'Strong PASSWORD'
encrypted_text = cipher.encrypt(text)
print('шифруем пароль: ',encrypted_text)

шифруем пароль:  b'gAAAAABiZt279DGHEKOcNtyTtzr6L6WwZA_fpT8eMHsR5Qk-Aihff13a3tcE6BVaSTO5rSK-AJmN0xH86MO9hcgdzeS4Cf3Pxg=='

decrypted_text = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_text)
print('дешефруем пароль: ',decrypted_text)

дешефруем пароль:  b'Strong PASSWORD'
```

Comment: Спасибо! А возможно ли внедрить скрипт в программу чтобы перехватить переменную до её шифровки?

Comment: Понятия не имею)) Если мой ответ Вас устраивает нажмите верхнюю стрелочку пожалуйста.

Comment: Извините, я не зарегистрирован и репутации не имею :(, но всё же спасибо за ваш ответ.

Comment: Ну и ладно)) был рад дать вам кусочек рабочего кода.